# Unknown CMake command "KDE4_INSTALL_ICONS"

Tags: kile

I'm trying to build Kile. When I type:

```
cmake "/home/user/Downloads/kile-2.1/src" 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/kile-install   
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -Wno-dev
```

then there is an error:

```
 CMake Error at data/icons/actions/CMakeLists.txt:1 (KDE4_INSTALL_ICONS):
 Unknown CMake command "KDE4_INSTALL_ICONS".
```

I'm using Cmake version 2.8.3. How to get rid off this error?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do something along the lines of apt-get build-deps kile, to ensure all the stuff you need to build kile is installed.

Then you may need to manually configure cmake with a few more variables: DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=[some src directory].  There is also a CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH variable that could have to be set.

I have a low level of confidence on this though.  Hopefully it may push you along in the right direction though.